# lavaan's estimated residuals output different than manually estimated residuals

Tags: variance, residuals, covariance-matrix, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I am using lavaan and wanted to check my residuals for my model. I use lavaan's residuals() or lavResiduals() function, but I also decided to do it myself manually by computing the difference between the model-implied and observed VCOV matrices. When I did this, I noticed that oddly lavaan's residuals look quite different from my own residuals. I have identified this with separate datasets as well. The numbers are just different. After inspecting some elements, the residuals from my manually computed residuals seem more accurate than lavaan's, which is quite confusing.

Below is a reproducible example, but also here is just one comparison:

Observed A1 and A2 covariance: -.560

Model implied A1 and A2 covariance: -.350

Manual A1 and A2 covariance: -.210

lavaan A1 and A2 covariance residual: -.127

Lavaan's A1 and A2 covariance, just as one example, seems to me to be incorrect. Am I missing something? Below is the full reproducible example with a subset of the matrices.

```
library(lavaan)
library(psych)
data(bfi)
# subset only columns used for factor analysis
bfiT <- bfi[grep("^A1$",colnames(bfi)):grep("^O5$",colnames(bfi))]
# VCOV matrix
bfiCov <- cov(bfiT,use="pairwise.complete.obs")
# number of observations
bfiObs <- nrow(bfiT)

# model structure
CFA_BFI <- 'A =~ A1 + A2 + A3 + A4 + A5
C =~ C1 + C2 + C3 + C4 + C5
E =~ E1 + E2 + E3 + E4 + E5
N =~ N1 + N2 + N3 + N4 + N5
O =~ O1 + O2 + O3 + O4 + O5'

# fit model
bfiFit <- cfa(CFA_BFI, sample.cov = bfiCov, sample.nobs = bfiObs)

# get lower triangle of VCOV
bfiCov[upper.tri(bfiCov)] <- NA
# manual residuals: observed minus model-implied VCOV
bfiCov - fitted(bfiFit)$cov
# lavaan residuals:
lavResiduals(bfiFit)$cov
```

Observed VCOV matrix:

```
bfiCov
               A1          A2           A3          A4           A5          C1           C2           C3
A1  1.98172388          NA           NA          NA           NA          NA           NA           NA
A2 -0.56022511  1.37363070           NA          NA           NA          NA           NA           NA
A3 -0.48584131  0.74162903  1.694770824          NA           NA          NA           NA           NA
A4 -0.30507471  0.58214833  0.696134951  2.18931289           NA          NA           NA           NA
A5 -0.32124097  0.57609473  0.828038485  0.57372364  1.583852702          NA           NA           NA
C1  0.04862476  0.13427623  0.156251056  0.16385925  0.187960689  1.54094125           NA           NA
C2  0.03035683  0.21006275  0.243534023  0.45259419  0.189159588  0.69971703  1.738037620           NA
C3 -0.03510886  0.29100742  0.220716441  0.25246176  0.218140478  0.49141939  0.603698956  1.660365770
C4  0.25073995 -0.23513014 -0.217313407 -0.30890486 -0.217241734 -0.57995546 -0.688188384 -0.596873855
C5  0.11471792 -0.23328058 -0.332013468 -0.58489099 -0.347356128 -0.50346031 -0.639973702 -0.714015916
E1  0.24401144 -0.39843559 -0.450285271 -0.26939100 -0.505403026 -0.04898562  0.037634969 -0.006154302
E2  0.20921795 -0.43622917 -0.597682266 -0.44618233 -0.671252951 -0.18332834 -0.127411082 -0.159988330
E3 -0.08843784  0.39698384  0.683238012  0.38099113  0.708590069  0.19507893  0.270828234  0.151811594
E4 -0.12026072  0.47933071  0.716673008  0.64095361  0.863886670  0.25420351  0.236429189  0.173295621
E5 -0.04094069  0.46017427  0.438478133  0.31596904  0.452453454  0.40956792  0.433844051  0.365498574
N1  0.36687931 -0.16117533 -0.172186999 -0.22981121 -0.387467837 -0.13105643 -0.042782514 -0.143366761
N2  0.29909980 -0.09055066 -0.175674502 -0.32524702 -0.361539163 -0.07636018 -0.018049120 -0.119192879
N3  0.23089915 -0.06670396 -0.086513799 -0.16669026 -0.273495867 -0.05840132  0.007344886 -0.137147548
N4  0.11517355 -0.16461366 -0.262506749 -0.38666370 -0.399684928 -0.18889801 -0.092763026 -0.225138770
N5  0.03795169  0.03633773 -0.077918714 -0.01696913 -0.154864002 -0.10718747  0.109208255 -0.025394651
O1  0.01999821  0.17298802  0.215170728  0.10214815  0.234887516  0.23441761  0.245617021  0.128689901
O2  0.17397074  0.02939576  0.002633542  0.08881309  0.001493055 -0.22070030 -0.084988836 -0.057702165
O3 -0.10838238  0.23410405  0.355975264  0.13024791  0.364631136  0.28852583  0.306325100  0.099028176
O4 -0.13290009  0.12519907  0.056545491 -0.06950682  0.025632682  0.16547172  0.090906337  0.026835025
O5  0.21360135 -0.13700252 -0.085700802  0.04078449 -0.080915216 -0.19323785 -0.096051840 -0.009747370
```

Model-implied VCOV

```
fitted(bfiFit)$cov
  A1     A2     A3     A4     A5     C1     C2     C3     C4     C5     E1     E2     E3     E4    
A1  1.981                                                                                           
A2 -0.350  1.373                                                                                    
A3 -0.452  0.717  1.694                                                                             
A4 -0.337  0.534  0.691  2.189                                                                      
A5 -0.405  0.642  0.830  0.619  1.583                                                               
C1 -0.106  0.168  0.217  0.161  0.194  1.540                                                        
C2 -0.123  0.195  0.252  0.188  0.226  0.508  1.737                                                 
C3 -0.110  0.175  0.226  0.168  0.202  0.455  0.529  1.660                                          
C4  0.151 -0.239 -0.309 -0.231 -0.277 -0.623 -0.725 -0.650  1.890                                   
C5  0.161 -0.255 -0.330 -0.246 -0.296 -0.666 -0.775 -0.694  0.951  2.651                            
E1  0.296 -0.470 -0.607 -0.453 -0.544 -0.213 -0.248 -0.222  0.305  0.325  2.661                     
E2  0.355 -0.562 -0.727 -0.542 -0.651 -0.255 -0.297 -0.266  0.365  0.389  1.020  2.576              
E3 -0.274  0.435  0.562  0.419  0.504  0.197  0.230  0.206 -0.282 -0.301 -0.788 -0.944  1.829       
E4 -0.325  0.516  0.667  0.497  0.597  0.234  0.272  0.244 -0.334 -0.357 -0.935 -1.119  0.865  2.124
```

Manual residuals:

```
bfiCov - fitted(bfiFit)$cov
       A1     A2     A3     A4     A5     C1     C2     C3     C4     C5     E1     E2     E3     E4    
A1  0.001                                                                                           
A2 -0.210  0.000                                                                                    
A3 -0.034  0.025  0.001                                                                             
A4  0.032  0.048  0.005  0.001                                                                      
A5  0.084 -0.066 -0.002 -0.045  0.001                                                               
C1  0.154 -0.033 -0.060  0.002 -0.006  0.001                                                        
C2  0.153  0.015 -0.008  0.265 -0.037  0.192  0.001                                                 
C3  0.075  0.116 -0.005  0.084  0.016  0.036  0.074  0.001                                          
C4  0.100  0.004  0.092 -0.078  0.060  0.044  0.037  0.053  0.001                                   
C5 -0.046  0.022 -0.002 -0.339 -0.051  0.162  0.135 -0.020  0.117  0.001                            
E1 -0.052  0.071  0.157  0.183  0.039  0.164  0.286  0.216 -0.094 -0.155  0.001                     
E2 -0.146  0.126  0.129  0.096 -0.020  0.072  0.170  0.106  0.080  0.297  0.205  0.001              
E3  0.186 -0.038  0.121 -0.038  0.205 -0.002  0.041 -0.054  0.135 -0.053  0.069  0.118  0.001       
E4  0.205 -0.036  0.050  0.144  0.267  0.020 -0.036 -0.071  0.118 -0.113 -0.061 -0.085 -0.039  0.001
```

Lavaan residuals:

```
lavResiduals(bfiFit)$cov


A1     A2     A3     A4     A5     C1     C2     C3     C4     C5     E1     E2     E3     E4    
A1  0.000                                                                                           
A2 -0.127  0.000                                                                                    
A3 -0.018  0.016  0.000                                                                             
A4  0.015  0.027  0.003  0.000                                                                      
A5  0.047 -0.045 -0.001 -0.024  0.000                                                               
C1  0.088 -0.023 -0.037  0.001 -0.004  0.000                                                        
C2  0.083  0.010 -0.005  0.136 -0.022  0.117  0.000                                                 
C3  0.041  0.077 -0.003  0.044  0.010  0.023  0.044  0.000                                          
C4  0.052  0.003  0.051 -0.038  0.035  0.026  0.021  0.030  0.000                                   
C5 -0.020  0.012 -0.001 -0.141 -0.025  0.080  0.063 -0.010  0.052  0.000                            
E1 -0.023  0.037  0.074  0.076  0.019  0.081  0.133  0.103 -0.042 -0.059  0.000                     
E2 -0.064  0.067  0.062  0.040 -0.010  0.036  0.080  0.051  0.036  0.113  0.078  0.000              
E3  0.098 -0.024  0.069 -0.019  0.120 -0.001  0.023 -0.031  0.072 -0.024  0.031  0.055  0.000       
E4  0.100 -0.021  0.026  0.067  0.145  0.011 -0.019 -0.038  0.059 -0.048 -0.025 -0.036 -0.020  0.000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just came cross the same problem, and found out that lavaan standardized the sample first before compuation. Acutually you can access this standardized observed covariance matrix by the command `lavInspect(fit, what = "sampstat")`. The fitted function and residual function are both standardized, just as Jeremy pointed out. Try

```
resid_lavaan = resid(fit)$cov 
resid_manually = lavInspect(fit, what = "sampstat")$cov - fitted(fit)$cov
```

You will find out that the resid_lavaan matches resid_manually.